# Encoding issues in Azure WebApps

Tags: azure, character-encoding, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to download an Excel file from my web page. In the local environment, everything works fine. But in Azure the encoding of the file name gets screwed up. I have already set the globalization tag in web.config as follows:

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

Here is how the response is built:

```
string name = v_NomeArquivo + ".xlsx";
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
Response.BinaryWrite(v_ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
Response.End();
```

The headers on Azure:

```
cache-control: private
content-disposition: attachment; filename=RelatÃ³rio Contrato Limpeza e HiginenizaÃ§Ã£o - 2020-10-06_10-55-26.xlsx
content-type: application/ms-excel
date: Tue, 06 Oct 2020 13:55:26 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
status: 200
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

And on local:

```
Cache-Control: private
content-disposition: attachment; filename=Relatório Contrato Limpeza e Higinenização - 2020-10-06_10-58-59.xlsx
Content-Type: application/ms-excel
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2020 13:58:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

The only difference is the filename getting messed up and the Transfer-Encoding, could it be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method.

Ex:

```
string name = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(v_NomeArquivo + ".xlsx", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I had to add a replace + for %20 at the end for the spaces to work, but thank you!